# android garbage collector information

Tags: android, listview, garbage-collection

I am writting an application that display a listView (with an image and some texts). I wrote my adapter, I recyle view and use a viewholder, all is working nice (but not very smoothly).

But by just having the listview displayed I can see in LogCat  thousand and thousand of objects freed by the gc (~12000 every 3s )
It doesn't seems very normal too me.

[image]

Is there a way to know what is the class of the most gced object or some kind of logs (or stats) of the gc ? For me to understand why my application is spamming new objects that are immediately gced ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I still can't comment, I add a new answer :-(
It all depends what you do inside your adapter. You write you have XML data. You do the parsing inside? The DOM classes produce unbelievable amounts of garbage (and are slow as hell). If you have to parse DOM, do it outside the adapter and/or cache the results.
Also, any enumeration you do (ex: `for (String x : xarray)`) produces lot of garbage. Same for String operations (consider using StringBuilder). Try to not use function-local variables, put them into some more global scope (if not, its garbage).
You display bitmaps? You create the Bitmap objects inside the adapter and then assign to the ImageView? Slow and lots of garbage, too.

I guess thats all of the common garbage and slow-UI-experience pitfalls. Anyone? ;)

Regards,
Oliver

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if you are downloading data - by your app or just any app. If not, you need to provide the code that is running so that we could have a look.

By the way, do something about your **zero acceptance**.

Comment: yes all the data displayed is downloaded. 
My ArrayAdapter is working from a List<MyObject> which is build from a xml file that I get. But I am sure the url of the xml is only get once and same for the image that are cached.